# value to the next thousand instead of nearest thousand

Tags: java

Sorry im new to java, currently i wanted to code the value to next thousand instead of nearest thousand. But i have no ideas how to do it. I tried `Math.round` but it's for roundest. Please guide me, any help would be appreciated .

Expected output that i looking for :

```
example 1) if the place values less than 999, it will direct change to 1000
```

May i know how can i code the math formula for this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `Math.ceil` for this.

```
// A quick code example :)
int val = 1400;
val = (int) (Math.ceil(val / 1000.0) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to write some custom code as follow

```
int leftdigit=value/1000;
int nextthousand=(leftdigit+1)*1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here Kindly note [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil%28double%29) returns double so you should use it properly as stated below as for integer value it won't work properly and ***integer division will be performed.***

```
    double data = 1100;
    data = Math.ceil(data / 1000) * 1000;
    System.out.println(data);
```

***OUTPUT***

```
2000.0
```

Comment: Thanks for reminded @TAsk as Math.ceil returns only double value

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from integers to floats leads to chaos, as for the same bit size, float mantissa length will always be smaller than integer size (IEEE-754 float mantissa is 23 bits vs 31 bits for the integer). Converting a large integer to float back and forth will not give the same integer after the conversion.

So here using `Math.ceil()` may work for integers or small long ints, but will break for large long values (63 bits).

Better use the following code (only works for value > 0):

```
int ii = ((i - 1) / 1000 + 1) * 1000;
```

or for long int version:

```
long ii = ((i - 1) / 1000 + 1) * 1000;
```

Does not unnecessarily overflow, keep precision even for large values, and probably way faster!

---

**Addenda**

As an example, the following java code:

```
    int largeint = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 63;
    float fl = (float)largeint;
    int largeint2 = (int)fl;
    System.out.println(largeint);
    System.out.println(largeint2);
```

Print:

```
    2147483584
    2147483647
```