# How to find the nearest highest thousand in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find the nearest highest 1000 from an integer

For example

```
let Num = 110;  //result will be 1000 
let num2 = 1280 // result will be 2000
```

I have tried the below example but it gives lowest value also

```
var round = Math.round(Num) // I am getting 100 only
```

Comment: `var round = Math.round(Num)` does NOT give 100 when Num = 110 - it results in 110 - because 110 is the rounded to nearest integer of 110

Comment: `Math.ceil(value / 1000) * 1000;` based on previous comment from @Beginner

Comment: `ceil`  solve that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [value to the next thousand instead of nearest thousand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422284/value-to-the-next-thousand-instead-of-nearest-thousand)

Comment: @Beginner, considering that question is Java and this one is JavaScript - it's useful, but I wouldn't dupe that, it could be too confusing for beginner javascript coders :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide by the tens place you want to round to and then multiply by that number.  Use `Math.ceil` so it always rounds up:

```js
let num1 = 110
let num2 = 1280
let num3 = -110

console.log( nearestThousand(num1) )  // 1000
console.log( nearestThousand(num2) )  // 2000
console.log( nearestThousand(num3) )  // 0 <-- determine expected behavior

function nearestThousand(n){
  return Math.ceil(n/1000)*1000
}
```

Comment: wow — looks like @itodd answered this in comments almost an hour ago.  Kudos to him.  Wonder if SO would benefit from a "promote to answer" feature to highlight comments that fundamentally answer/solve the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var result = Math.round(val/1000)*1000 == 0 ? 1000 : Math.round(val/1000)*1000;
```

and if you want to round to next thousandth value, use this

```
var result = Math.round(val/1000)*1000 + 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nearestHighestThousand(value) {
    if (value < 1) {
        return 1000;
    } else if (value > 9000) {
        return 9000;
    } else {
        return Math.ceil(value / 1000) * 1000;
    }
}

var round = nearestHighestThousand(num);
```

Comment: The first two conditions don't seem to serve a purpose and are incorrect. Negative values should not return `1000`, and values over `9000` should not return `9000`. `return Math.ceil(value / 1000) * 1000;` on it's own should be sufficient.